# Saving Encrypted Field on Slick

Tags: scala, slick

A simple question that I can't figure out (nowhere in Google or documentation - perhaps its obvious, but not to me). I am using slick with Play! Framework 2.1 and I want to save some sensitive user information in database. I want to encrypt the data everytime it's about to be saved (and in memory, when constructed in a `case class`) and decrypt the data everytime it's needed. The data is an OAuth `access_token`.

Here's my (simplified) code:

```
case class User(id: Option[Int] = None,
                name: String,
                email: String,
                oauthToken: Option[String] = None)
```

The object:

```
object Users extends Table[User]("User") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def oauthToken = column[String]("oauthToken", O.Nullable)

  def * = id.? ~
          name ~
          email ~
          oauthToken.? <> (User, User.unapply _)
}
```

What I want to do is to encrypt the `oauthToken` everytime the `User` case class is constructed. and decrypt it everytime `user.oauthToken` is called. For now my best guess is to change the getter and setter of `oauthToken`, but as far as I know, we can't really do that in Scala (not to mention the effect on Slick).

What should I do to get encryption/decryption on field?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
// get user
Users.where(_.id is Some(1)).map(decodeUser)

def decodeUser(u: User) =
  u.copy(oauthToken = u.oauthToken.map(/* do decoding */))

// store user
for{
  model <- userForm.bindFromRequest
  id <- Users(encodeUser(model)).insert
} yield id

def encodeUser(u: User) =
  u.copy(oauthToken = u.oauthToken.map(/* do encoding */))
```

Comment: does this means I don't save the encrypted tokens on database? And I have to call `encodeUser` and `decodeUser` everytime I want to insert / get user?

Comment: ah yes I got it now. I'll abstract them for easier use though. Thank you very much!